# Import existing Android project in Eclipse: no gen source folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, project, adt

I'm trying to import an android project into Eclipse (from Git, but I don't think it's relevant), and I can't run or compile it because I get these errors:

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0. Please fix project properties.  Serval-Video-Discovery      line 1  Android ADT Problem 
Project 'Serval-Video-Discovery' is missing required source folder: 'gen'   Serval-Video-Discovery      Build path  Build Path Problem
```

I think the first one isn't really a big problem, even if I don't really understand the warning.

The funny thing is that the "gen" folder exists on the filesystem; furthermore, I can't try to create it because it already exists !

What should I do to solve this issue?

Here is the GitHub repo I'm trying to import from: https://github.com/rbochet/Serval-Video-Discovery

Comment: Clean the project and then run.

Comment: Just try Restarting eclipse if it doesn't work after trying wat Sandy said.

Comment: If cleaning the project and restarting Eclipse isn't enough, try removing the `gen` directory from the file system (it's automatically generated, as the name implies). Then run Clean project. This did it for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
Package Explorer -> Right click the project -> "Android Tools" -> "Fix Project Properties"
Project -> Clean
```

Fixes without having to restart eclipse

Answer (score 13):

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0. Please fix project properties.
```

I had the same problem but non of these answers helped me. I found my solution [here](http://kyleclegg.com/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0/):

> Package Explorer -> Right click the
>   project -> "Android Tools" -> "Fix
>   Project Properties"

Comment: I used your trick few days ago... I have to say that the "fix the issue button" is always welcome. Good one!

Comment: Why did I have to search 2 hours only to find the RIGHT MOUSE BUTTON here, Everybody else answering questions, assumed that you know that. But there's beginners too. Txs

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but solved in the following way

```
Package Explorer -> Right click the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> your project name/gen -> click on Remove -> Click on Add Folder -> check gen -> Ok -> Ok
```

Comment: "Fix project properties" and "Clean" didn't work.

But this worked for me. I had this issue after formatting my computer and re-installing and re-importing my project. Eclipse did not prompt error and ran the last installed program on the phone instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click and delete the gen directory from eclipse. If not, try the fix project properties above.

Answer (score 0):

If gen folder is missing under project after importing an existing project into workplace, just create a gen folder under project and that will fix the above error.